# How should I determine which menuitems to show on my ASP MVC project that consumes an ASP API

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, rest, service

In my new project I need a REST-service that will contain all the logic and data of the system. For now we need a website and a desktop application to consume this service and later more can be added.

The website, desktop-applications and others should just be 'interfaces' for the service.

The project will contain a few roles that can perform certain actions.

My question:
How should I go about determining which menuitems should be visible to a logged-in user?
In my website (ASP.NET MVC) I can login and the service gives me a token I can use to (try and) access resources.
But trying to access a resource will only tell me if I can access it after the request(200 or 403).
So how would I prevent users from seeing menuitems that they cannot access anyway?

Comment: can you not get the menuitems from Rest service?

Comment: I don't think the RESTservice should know about menu-items. I want to show them based on the access rights of the logged in user. But I'm not sure if I should query/store those rights from the RESTservice or if there is another way to do this.

Comment: I have same situation. I save access rights and resource urls ( controllers and action names) in my DB and I generate menu by js on load home page.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't get your point.
but this may be helpfull
[Secure a Web API with Individual Accounts and Local Login in ASP.NET Web API 2.2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/individual-accounts-in-web-api)

**Edit 1** 
I have three kinds of users Students and Instructors and Admins this is the identity login Action

```
 public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return View(model);
            }

            ApplicationUser signedUser = UserManager.FindByEmail(model.Email);
            var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(signedUser.UserName, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: true);

            switch (result)
            {
                case SignInStatus.Success:
                    if (signedUser.UserAccessType == "Student")
                    {
                        var ObjStudent = dbContext.Students.Find(signedUser.Id);                 
                        TempData["Student"] = ObjStudent;

                    }
                    else if (signedUser.UserAccessType == "Instructor")
                    {
                        var ObjInstructor = dbContext.Instructors.Find(signedUser.Id);
                        TempData["Instructor"] = ObjInstructor;
                    }
                    else if (signedUser.UserAccessType == "Admin")
                    {
                        var ObjAdmin = dbContext.Users.Find(signedUser.Id);
                        TempData["Admin"] = ObjAdmin;
                    }
                    return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
                case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
                    return View("Lockout");
                case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
                    return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = model.RememberMe });
                case SignInStatus.Failure:
                default:
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");
                    return View(model);
            }
        }
```

then in the layout :

```
@using AdminstrationSysytem_v1.Models
@{ 
    var Student = TempData["Student"] as Student;
    var Instructor = TempData["Instructor"] as Instructors;
    var Admin = TempData["Admin"] as ApplicationUser;
    TempData.Keep();
}
```

menu items based on user type :

```
  <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="https://github.com/AlameerAshraf">About</a></li>
            @if (TempData.Count != 0)
            {
                if (TempData.ContainsKey("Student"))
                {
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Student Profile", "UserProfile", "Students", Student)</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Evalute Instructors", "Evalute", "Students", Student)</li>
                }
                else if (TempData.ContainsKey("Instructor"))
                {
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Instructor Profile", "UserProfile", "Instructors", Instructor)</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Permissions", "GivePermission", "Instructors", Instructor)</li>
                }
                else if (TempData.ContainsKey("Admin"))
                {
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Admin Profile", "UserProfile", "Instructors", Admin)</li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Studnts Panel<span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Attendance Reception For"+" "+DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"), "AttendanceReception", "Attendance")</li>
                            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Report of Absence" + " " + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"), "Report", "Attendance")</li>
                            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Report of Attendance" + " " + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"), "ReportOfAttendance", "Attendance")</li>
                            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Attendance Reprots in time", "Reportattendanceinperiod", "Attendance")</li>
                            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Absence Reprots in time", "Reportabsenceinperiod", "Attendance")</li>
                            <li>@Html.ActionLink(" Quartz library resposible for calling this action daily", "Claculatebsence", "Attendance")</li>
                             @*RepoertAttendanceTaskSchedular Class in Models*@
                            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Students", "StudentsList", "Students")</li>
                            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Students", "SubmitToDepartment", "Students")</li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                }
            }
        </ul>
        @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I know that page however it does not answer my question. Sorry I haven't made my "problem" clear enough. Maybe this helps: I have 2 resources A and B. Some users can access A and some can access B or both. I thought about protecting them with 'roles' or 'claims'. This is all done in the API. On the website (ASP MVC) I want to know if I should display the menu items for the resources based on their access rights. Maybe I should just create an API endpoint to request the access rights? Is that a proper way to do this?

Comment: Understood I did something like that when the user signed in I save the returned object from DB  in tempdate and in each time I check for that object and based on its type the menu items appear and hide.

Comment: @SEG.Veenstra I Updated the answer check it out.

Comment: Thank you for your effort but I think this is only part of the solution. The main story of my problem is that I need to get the role(student, admin or instructor in you sample) from the RESTservice preferably at login.
So from my MVC project I would call api/login or /token to get a token normally. In my MVC project I then have a token to try and get resources.
So I would like to know which role/claims the user has so I could do what you did in your answer, showing menuitems based on that role. I Wonder if it's 'save' to store these roles/claims clientsided.